# Как сравнить производительность разных виртуальных машин?

Tags: виртуализация, производительность

Пытаюсь выбрать виртуальную машину, и не могу понять как их сравнивать. Когда читаю описание любой ВМ - вижу много слов про используемые технологии, и почему они делают эту ВМ самой быстрой. Но ведь не могут все они быть самыми быстрыми, какие-то из них же должны быть быстрее других?

Как сравнивать разные виртуальные машины?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1.** Наиболее быстрыми являются виртуальные машины контейнерного типа - все контейнеры используют общее ядро и общие модули уровня ядра, но служебные структуры каждого процесса инициализированы особым образом, что создает иллюзию совершенно разных серверов.

Примеры контейнеров - OpenVZ, Docker. *Работают только на линуксе, потому что над другими ОС невозможно надругаться настолько же сильно.*

**2.** Следом за контейнерами в порядке уменьшения производительности идет паравиртуализация. Паравиртуализация - это запуск гостевой ОС полностью на уровне пользователя, для этого для нужной ОС готовят специальные драйвера, которые подменяют все те модули ядра, которым ранее требовался доступ к привилегиям уровня ядра (ring 0 на архитектуре x86/64).

Пример паравиртуальных машин - XEN, User mode linux.

Ограничение - гостевая ОС для работы в паравиртуальном режиме должна быть совместима с используемым гипервизором. Зачастую это ограничение можно читать как "гостевая ОС должна быть линуксом", хотя есть и некоторые исключения.

**3.** Следующие по тяжести реализации - гипервизоры, использующие аппаратную виртуализацию. Это опять XEN, KVM, VirtualBox, WMWare, Hyper-V и QEMU (в режиме KQEMU)...

Здесь уже нет никаких ограничений на гостевую ОС, кроме наличия под нее драйверов для виртуальных устройств. Но многие реализации эмулируют в качестве "виртуальных" реально существующие устройства, что упрощает проблему с драйверами.

Но тут надо понимать, что несмотря на возможность полной виртуализации на каждой из этих ВМ, все они могут использовать частичную паравиртуализацию для ускорения работы. Поэтому если поставить на ВМ специальный набор "гостевых" драйверов - ее работа ускорится и могут появиться новые возможности. Поэтому при выборе ВМ надо учитывать предполагаемую гостевую ОС и смотреть, какие гостевые драйвера для нее есть.

Обычно считается, что XEN, KVM и VirtualBox быстрее работают когда гостевая ОС - linux, а WMWare и Hyper-V - когда гостевая ОС - Windows.

**4.** Последний класс, самый медленный - эмуляторы. Снимают ограничение по архитектуре процессора (можно эмулировать ARM на x64 или наоборот) - но работают еще медленнее прошлых классов. Пример - QEMU, BOCHS.

У эмуляторов тоже есть приемы для ускорения выполнения. Но сравнение эмуляторов выходит уже за рамки этого вопроса.

Comment: Отметь свой ответ ответом.

Comment: а какой закрыли?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, уже не могу найти. Тема вопроса была точно такая же, но в поиске он уже не ищется, а вкладку с ним я закрыл.

Comment: Тема была плохо сформулирована, и видно автор вместо правки выбрал удаление. В данной формулировке все вполне прилично, плюсанул.

Comment: Хорошо на свои же вопросы отвечать. Точно знаешь, что имел в виду автор вопроса. :)

Comment: Хорошо (только основной вопрос `что и когда ставить`) остался без ответа, но все равно +). / Наверное стоит добавить, что в 1) guest и host это одна и та же ОС (т.е. в этом случае нельзя сделать, скажем, windows контейнер в linux (или AIX, ...)), а также сказать о сходности контейнеров и chroot environment. / Кстати, для полноты описания неплохо бы упомянуть IBM (AIX) и HP (hp-ux) WPAR-ы и м.б. дать ссылочки  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization и др.) / (Ждем продолжения о внутренней архитектуре, как оно программируется изнутри? :))

Comment: @avp, у меня написано более сильное утверждение в пункте 1 - у всех ОС даже версия ядра и наборы драйвером совпадают, не то что название. chroot же отличается тем, что он никак не ограничивает права рута, в отличии от контейнеров. Я бы не назвал их похожими.

Comment: Для новичка из вашего описания  (по крайней мере если я ставлю себя на его место)  совершенно не следует, что не может быть (на самом деле я-то знаю, что не может) контейнеров **разного типа** (каждый тип для своей версии guest) в рамках одного host-а. / Что же касается chroot, то отличий гораздо больше (не только root-isolation), но все же для ряда практических задач они схожи. Можно описание chroot вынести в отдельный пункт (хотя, вообще-то он (chroot) не слишком согласуется с интуитивным лейтмотивом вопроса в текущей формулировке).

Comment: @avp: согласен, для меня это не было очевидно.